# Посоветуйте пожалуйста курсы по Unreal Engine C++

Tags: c++, c++11, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine, unreal-engine-5

Хочу найти хороший курс по плюсам и Unreal Engine, для создание RPG Shooter от 1 лица или что то подобное. Я уже много искал и на "Udemy" во вкладке RPG , но там не было того, что мне нужно, а именно полной системы инвентаря с функцией Drag&Drop предмета в инвентаре и нормальным ИИ. какие есть реально хорошие курсы на эту тему